# How to make an object emit light in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

How do I achieve this effect in Cycles?

Comment: Do you mean emit light?

Comment: yup yup to emit light.

Comment: You want to use an emission shader.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make an object emit light you use an *emission shader*.  Go to the *materials* tab on the *properties editor*, then add a new material and change the shader from the default *diffuse* to *emission*.